# Help understanding "one rather than the other of two present-day phenomena" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "The argument proceeds by presenting evidence that a past phenomenon is more similar to **one rather than the other of two present-day phenomena.**"

I am having problem understanding this sentence, because of the part "one rather than the other ... phenomena." Can someone explain it in detail?

Comment: There are two phenomena in the present, let's say A and B. Let the past phenomenon be P. P is more similar to A than to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand why this is confusing.  It's confusing for me as well.  But let's try and interpret it from end of the sentence, moving toward the front:

> two-present day phenomena

There are two phenomena.  Got it.

> one rather than the other of two ... phenomena

They're talking about the first one and not the other one of the two phenomena.  Got it.

> A past phenomena is more similar to one rather than the other ...

A past phenomena is similar to the first of the two phenomena, not the second.

> presenting evidence that ...

There is evidence to support the following statement (about the similar phenomena)

> The argument proceeds by presenting evidence that ...

Ok, so now we get the entire picture.  There is an argument, the argument presents evidence, the evidence supports the similarity of a past phenomena with one (but not the other) of two present-day phenomena.

Sometimes working from the back to the front is useful.  Sometimes not.